# Insert objects into other objects before the innerHTML with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my current tooltip:

```
<div class="tooltip" style="position: absolute; top: 1298px; left: 382.5px; display: none; ">this is where the tooltip text goes. You are quite the cool!</div>
```

Ignore the fact that it has inline CSS for a sec (sorry)...

Ok so I need to insert 3 spans into it - 1.5 before and 1.5 after the HTML so it looks like this in the end:

```
<div class="tooltip" style="position: absolute; top: 1298px; left: 382.5px; display: none; "><span class="tooltop"></span><span class="toolmid">this is where the tooltip text goes. You are quite the cool!</span><span class="toolbot"></span></div>
```

but of course don't know the best way to do this...

Essentially it would look like this:

> (existing div) (beginning span /) (middle span) [existing innerHTML] (/ middle span) (ending span /) (/existing div)

No idea.

Comment: What do you mean by -1.5 before and 1.5 after?

Comment: sorry that was confusing... I need to incase the innerHTML of an existing div (tooltip) with the following before: <span class="tooltop"></span><span class="toolmid"> & the following after: </span><span class="toolbot"></span>

Comment: How does one insert half of a `<span>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`wrapAll`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) existing content, then [`prepend`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) the top and [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) the bottom

```
var tooltip = $('.tooltip');                            //cache tooltip

tooltip.contents().wrapAll('<span class="toolmid" />'); //wrap existing contents
tooltip.prepend('<span class="tooltop">');              //prepend the top
tooltip.append('<span class="toolbot">');               //append the bottom
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

HTML

```
<div class="tooltip" style="position: absolute; top: 1298px; left: 382.5px; display: none; ">this is where the tooltiip text goes. You are quite the cool!</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(".tooltip").each(function(index, tooltip) {
    tooltip.innerHTML = '<span class="tooltop"></span><span class="toolmid">' + tooltip.innerHTML + '</span><span class="toolbot"></span>';
});
```

This code will find all of the elements with the "tooltip" class and add in the spans.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.existing-div-selector')
    .append(
        $('<span class="tooltop"></span><span class="toolmid">' + someContentVariable + '</span><span class="toolbot"></span>')
    );
```

jQuery allows you to build up DOM snippets from strings that it'll parse and create DOM elements from.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('<span class="tooltop"></span><span class="toolmid">' + someContentVariable + 
            '</span><span class="toolbot"></span>').
                         appendTo('your_div_selector');
```